# How to share a qr code image using expo-sharing?

Tags: react-native, expo, qr-code

I generate a qrcode using 'react-native-qrcode-svg' `<QRCode size={100} value={deepLink} getRef={(c) => (svg = c)} />`and I want to share the QR image using expo sharing, I tried this way but didn't work, gives me this error when sharing `[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Only local file URLs are supported (expected scheme to be 'file', got 'data'.]`
I have a share button that calls this function

```
var svg: any;
 let openShareDialogAsync = async () => {
    if (!(await Sharing.isAvailableAsync())) {
      alert(`Uh oh, sharing isn't available on your platform`);
      return;
    }
    svg.toDataURL((link: any) => {
      console.log(link);//the base64 string
      Sharing.shareAsync('data:image/png;base64,' + link);
     
    });
  };
```

I'll appreciate it If someone can help me with it. I tried using react-native-share but didn't work with expo, I believe I need to eject the project in order to work with it.

Comment: Can you upload the image to the server and generate a permanent image to share.

Comment: Can you tell me more about how to do it? and do you mean every time I generate a qr I would save it?

Comment: Yeah, You can use  Cloud Object Storage providers like  AWS S3 or Firebase Storage, After  uploading, they generate image URL which can use in expo share